# Declarar la segunda dimension de un array escalonado

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Tengo que hacer un array escalonado, pero no se como hacerlo para que a la hora de preguntar se declaren las columnas del array dentro del bucle, el programa deberia hacer esto tantas veces como jugadores le pongas.

### Salida del programa

Entra el número de jugadores : 3

Entra el número de partidos jugados por el jugador 1 : 2 
Entra los puntos del partido 1 : 11 
Entra los puntos del partido 2 : 15

Entra el número de partidos jugados por el jugador 2 : 3 
Entra los puntos del partido 1 : 8 
Entra los puntos del partido 2 : 5 
Entra los puntos del partido 3 : 15

Entra el número de partidos jugados por el jugador 3 : 2 
Entra los puntos del partido 1 : 21 
Entra los puntos del partido 2 : 18

he intentado hacer esto, pero solo me llena el ultimo jugador:

```
    //Variables
    System.out.print("Entra el número de jugadores: ");
    int numjuga = Integer.parseInt(teclat.readLine());
    int array[][] = new int[numjuga][];
    int numparti = 0;

    //Bucle para pedir partidos y puntuacion
    for ( int i=0; i<array.length; i++ ) {

        System.out.printf("Entra el número de partidos jugados por el jugado %d: ", i+1);
        numparti = Integer.parseInt(teclat.readLine());
        array = new int[numjuga][numparti];

        for ( int k=0; k<array[0].length; k++ ) { 
            System.out.printf("Entra los puntos del partido %d: ",k+1);
            array[i][k] = Integer.parseInt(teclat.readLine());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que lo que cuando se ejecuta `array = new int[numjuga][numparti];` estás iniciando de nuevo el array, entonces se pierden todos los datos.

Intenta poniendo el código así:

```
array[i] = new int[numparti];
```

Comment: aaaah! vale, una vez lo he puesto asi ya me ha funcionado, muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada, si te ha servido te invito a que marques la respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando llegas a `array = new int[numjuga][numparti];`, tal y como dijo FrEqDe, te estas cargando la lista existente por una nueva. Su respuesta debería de valerte. Yo te ofrezco una alternativa ya que no soy partidario de listas fijas

Optaría por cambiar `int array[][]` por `hashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>` ya que te olvidarias de tamaños fijos.

```
//Variables
System.out.print("Entra el número de jugadores: ");
int numjuga = Integer.parseInt(teclat.readLine());
Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> array = HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
int numparti = 0;

//Bucle para pedir partidos y puntuacion
for ( int i=0; i<array.length; i++ ) {

    System.out.printf("Entra el número de partidos jugados por el jugado %d: ", i+1);
    numparti = Integer.parseInt(teclat.readLine());
    List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList();
    array.put(numjuga, lista);

    for ( int k=0; k<numparti; k++ ) { 
        System.out.printf("Entra los puntos del partido %d: ",k+1);
        lista.add(Integer.parseInt(teclat.readLine()));
    }
}
```

(puede que tenga algún error de falta un ( o un ; ya que no tenia un IDE a mano para verificarlo 100%)

Comment: muchas gracias, la verdad es que justo empiezo a programar y no acabo de entender lo que has hecho, así que de momento me quedo con lo que me ha puesto FrEqDe.

Comment: Te lo explico rapido. Un arrayList de primeras es una lista dinamica. No necesitas indicarle el tamaño maximo de este y puedes ir metiendo todos los objetos que quieras. El hashmap es un poco mas complejo. Se basa en tuplas de dos objetos, siendo el primero la clave y el segundo el valor. Con el hashMap, sabiendo la clave, puedes sacar el campo valor